# undefined reference to QCamera constructor

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I'm writing a simple camera project for Raspberry Pi, via cross compiler visual studio.

**step 1:** I created a qt project using visual studio

**step 2:** coding for project

When coding for project, I declared

```
QCamera camera;
camera = new QCamera(cameraInfo);
```

When I built the project, I got this error:

> Error VGDB1000    undefined reference to `QCamera::QCamera(QCameraInfo
>   const&, QObject*)'

Comment: ask question correctly and show code right format

Comment: While this question "fits" this forum, I do believe you will get better answers and more experienced users in [the dedicated raspberry pi forum](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)